# Mui Data Grid - How can I add a Summary row on each page of the grid as a last row which can scroll with other rows

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I want to add a summary row to the MUI `DataGrid` component. I am getting the total from my API response. I want to display this summary row on each page of the grid.  It should be the last row and should scroll with other rows.

Like the below screen shot:
[image]

Is there any way to achieve this. Really struggling to get this feature.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.